# Highstocks not showing stock tools

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to plot a time-series but I am not getting the stock tools as in the left-side of this chart. Example from the highstocks website: [enter link description here](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui)

[image: GUI example]

The code with options:

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'


class Graph extends React.Component {
    getOptions = (dataSets) => {
        return {
            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'left'
                },
                height: '80%',
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'left'
                },
                top: '80%',
                height: '20%',
                offset: 0
            }],

            title: {
                text: 'Summary'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'INFY',
                data: dataSets.data
            }]
        };
    };

    render() {
        const {dataSets} = this.props;
        const options = this.getOptions(dataSets);

        return (
            <div>
                <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    constructorType={'stockChart'}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Graph;
```

Here is what is rendered:

[image]

What is going wrong?

**EDIT:**

After applying the suggestions by @ppotaczek. I get this:

[image]

Updated code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import indicatorsAll from "highcharts/indicators/indicators-all";
import annotationsAdvanced from "highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced";
import priceIndicator from "highcharts/modules/price-indicator";
import fullScreen from "highcharts/modules/full-screen";
import stockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";


indicatorsAll(Highcharts);
annotationsAdvanced(Highcharts);
priceIndicator(Highcharts);
fullScreen(Highcharts);
stockTools(Highcharts);


class Graph extends React.Component {
    getOptions = (dataSets) => {
        return {
            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'left'
                },
                height: '80%',
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'left'
                },
                top: '80%',
                height: '20%',
                offset: 0
            }],

            title: {
                text: 'Summary'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'INFY',
                data: dataSets.data
            }]
        };
    };

    render() {
        const {dataSets} = this.props;
        const options = this.getOptions(dataSets);

        return (
            <div>
                <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    constructorType={'stockChart'}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Graph;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need load CSS styles and import and initialize all of the required modules:

```
import indicatorsAll from "highcharts/indicators/indicators-all";
import annotationsAdvanced from "highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced";
import priceIndicator from "highcharts/modules/price-indicator";
import fullScreen from "highcharts/modules/full-screen";
import stockTools from "highcharts/modules/stock-tools";

indicatorsAll(Highcharts);
annotationsAdvanced(Highcharts);
priceIndicator(Highcharts);
fullScreen(Highcharts);
stockTools(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-3s8v7

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools

Comment: It doesn't work. I have updated the question with the details.

Comment: Hi @conquester, Please check my example more carefully. As I wrote before, you must also load CSS styles.

Comment: Pardon me but I am new to frontend development. Infact, I just started using React, Javascript & CSS last week. Can you please point me to how to load the css? I am just using npx create-app to create the app.

Comment: Ok. I was missing the import style.css at the top. I did that. But even in the example given in the answer....one cannot add anything from the toolbar. For ex; Try adding ATR. Is this limitation of the data or something is wrong?

Comment: Ok, no problem. You need to add `https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css` and `https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css`. Yes, it's probably caused by too little data, for example the `measure` tool works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. I am just struck by the incosistency of javascript. Never been a frontend coder and this is not the right place to rant. But I do have to tell that javascript seems like a one hell of mess from a java/python perspective. Highcharts is great though.

Comment: I have done this now. Sorry, I forgot in the urgency of the moment.